# Controlling Sound on flash video with Play/pause/stop buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, actionscript

I have a flash video that is short, has sound, and I've got Play Pause and Stop buttons.

Without sound, it works perfectly. It autoplays, you can hit pause and it pauses, and play resumes where it leaves off. Hitting stop goes to an empty frame if someone wants to turn it off.

I have audio inside my library, and would like connect the audio with the same elements. I've been researching for awhile now, and I've not come up with a solution yet, and having a hard time.

Here is my ActionScript code for my currently working buttons:

```
StopBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopplaying);
function stopplaying(Event:MouseEvent):void {
    stop()
}

PlayBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startplaying);
function startplaying(Event:MouseEvent):void {
    play()
}

CloseBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, close);
function close(Event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(240)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Sound` and `SoundChannel` to do this. And for pause you'll have to save the current play position so that you can continue from there:

```
var audio:Sound = new audioFromLibrary(); //linkage name
var soundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var audioPosition:Number = 0;

//PLAY:
soundChannel = audio.play(audioPosition);

//PAUSE:
audioPosition = soundChannel.position;
soundChannel.stop();

//STOP:
soundChannel.stop();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I'm getting closer I think. I'm getting an error 2068 invalid sound on the "startplaying" section... and it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Here is what the code has been modified to.

Comment: 'var snd:Sound = new Sound();
var soundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var audioPosition:Number = 0;'

Comment: 'StopBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopplaying);
function stopplaying(Event:MouseEvent):void {
 stop()
 audioPosition = soundChannel.position;
 soundChannel.stop();
}

PlayBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startplaying);
function startplaying(Event:MouseEvent):void {
 play()
 soundChannel = snd.play(audioPosition);
}

CloseBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, close);
function close(Event:MouseEvent):void {
 gotoAndStop(240)
 soundChannel.stop();
}'

Comment: Ah yes, this `var snd:Sound = new Sound();` should be `var snd:Sound = new linkage_name_of_your_library_audio();`

Comment: var snd:Sound = new snd();

Comment: It's saying undefined method for snd();

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very flash savvy at the moment, hah.

Comment: Yes, you can't actually use the same name for it, so try `var snd0:Sound = new snd();` and use `snd0` in later code :)

Comment: Ah, the variable. Got it. Let me try that.

Comment: Awesome, thats definitely gotten it somewhere. Just need to work on the if then's to not play the track over itself. Thanks so much!!!!! Been racking my brain muscles.

Comment: No problems, enjoy! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89946/discussion-between-byarsulik-and-kaarto).